# Create a cypher relationship if it doesn't exist

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Overall goal of the cypher is to assign a status to an item and keep previous statuses as an archive.

I have a list if items as nodes in neo4j 3.0. Each item can have one of the following statuses: Live, Dead, Missing or any other statuses I define.

First I create a node with the status live.

```
Merge (n:Item {itemID: '123'}
  ON CREATE set n.itemID = '123, ...
  ON MATCH  set n.DTS = ...
WITH n
MATCH (st:Status {name:'Live'})
MERGE (n)-[CURRENT_STATUS {DTS: ...}]->(st)
```

This works fine.

Now when the user wants to change the status, I would like to make a copy of the CURRENT_STATUS, then delete it, and create a new one with the new status. I need to do this only if the new status is different from the current status. Here is what I tried (below 'Missing' is the new status that should be assigned to the item):

```
Merge (n:Item {itemID: '123'}
  ON CREATE set n.itemID = '123, ...
  ON MATCH  set n.modifiedDTS = ...
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[cs:CURRENT_STATUS]-(st:Status)
WITH n, st, CASE st.name WHEN 'Missing' THEN [] ELSE [n] END as array, cs
FOREACH (x in array | 
   CREATE (x)-[prevStatus:PREVIOUS_STATUS {DTS: cs.DTS}]->(st)
   DELETE cs
   CREATE (x)-[newStatus:CURRENT_STATUS {DTS: 123}]->(st2:Status {name:'Missing'})
)
return *;
```

Unfortunately this does not work. The loop is deleting the existing status but never creates the PREVIOUS_STATUS or CURRENT_STATUS relationships. There is no error.

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The problem is that I am using x inside the loop instead of n. I am leaving this open in the case somebody else has a better suggestion since I am still a newbie in cypher.

Answer (score 0):

*Aside: It seems to me your original approach should have worked. Perhaps you are using an older version of neo4j?*

Your original Cypher could cause `n` to end up with multiple `:PREVIOUS_STATUS` relationships, and you'd have to order them by `DTS` to find the most recent one. I have modified your Cypher a bit to not only use the "n instead of x" workaround from your answer, but to also chain the statuses together in reverse chronological order (so that no computation is needed to get the ordering).

```
MERGE (n:Item {itemID: '123'}
  ON CREATE SET ...
  ON MATCH  SET n.modifiedDTS = ...
WITH n
MATCH (n)-[cs:CURRENT_STATUS]-(st:Status)
WITH n, st, cs, CASE st.name WHEN 'Missing' THEN [] ELSE [1] END as array
FOREACH (x in array |
   CREATE (n)-[newStatus:CURRENT_STATUS {DTS: 123}]->(st2:Status {name:'Missing'})
   CREATE (st2)-[prevStatus:PREVIOUS_STATUS {DTS: cs.DTS}]->(st)
   DELETE cs
)
return *;
```

After several iterations with the same item, this query would create chains like this:

```
(:Item)-[:CURRENT_STATUS]->(:Status)-[:PREVIOUS_STATUS]->(:Status)-[:PREVIOUS_STATUS]->(:Status)-> ...
```

*By the way, in the `ON CREATE` clause, there was no need to `SET n.itemID = '123'`, since the `MERGE` would have already set that property for you.*